# M68k - IDA Pro 24-bit addressing?

Tags: ida, 68000

I'm trying to disassemble a BIOS image for the 68000, and I'm having trouble getting IDA Pro 6.5 to correctly cross-reference addresses.

For those who aren't aware, the Motorola 68000 has a couple of interesting features/quirks related to addressing:

1. When given a 16-bit absolute address, the processor sign-extends it to 32 bits before dereferencing it.
2. The 68K uses a 24-bit address bus, so the high byte in a 32-bit address is ignored.

The original authors of this BIOS took advantage of these properties in a number of places to save a few bytes: for any address above 0xFF8000, it's possible to specify the address using only two bytes instead of four. For example, if I wanted to access the memory at address 0xFF9134:

```
lea (0x9134).w, a0
< sign extension >
lea (0xFFFF9134).l, a0
< discard high byte >
lea 0xFF9134, a0
```

The problem I'm running into is that IDA Pro is performing the sign extension, but then considers the entire 32-bit address instead of only the lower 24 bits. IDA ends up trying to cross-reference addresses that don't (or at least shouldn't) exist, and any segments/code/data I have in the 0xFF8000-0xFFFFFF address range get completely ignored.

I'm still new to IDA Pro, so I don't know if this would be solvable with a script, let alone how to write such a thing. Is there a way I can get the disassembler to correctly handle this dirty/clever addressing trick?

Comment: Maybe you can just make a copy of the memory range 0xFF8000 - 0xFFFFFF to 0xFFFF8000, so IDA Pro finds it in both places.

Comment: Not so cool. Such code cannot be ported to 32 bit 030 or 040's... bad practice. But at the time those were common hacks to gain speed. Self modifying code was another. In ROM it doesnt work that well though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My decision was to create custom_ana callback and then change every operand address as the following: op.add &= 0xFFFFFF.
But it is not so easy. Because you don't have fully recognized "cmd" at this moment, and you must prepare it by your own code.